# R code to extract two columns (one of which has multiple text strings which need to be parsed) into a named list of character vectors

Tags: r

I currently have a situation where I have a dataframe where I need to convert two of the columns a specified format. Example of the data in each column:

Column 1: `Some_text_String`

Column 2:

```
GO:0048046^cellular_component^apoplast`GO:0005618^cellular_component^cell wall`GO:0005576^cellular_component^extracellular region`GO:0099503^cellular_component^secretory vesicle`GO:0004252^molecular_function^serine-type endopeptidase activity`GO:0080001^biological_process^mucilage extrusion from seed coat`GO:0048359^biological_process^mucilage metabolic process involved in seed coat development`GO:0010214^biological_process^seed coat development
```

So I have two problems. I need to parse the second column so that only the `GO:XXXXXXXX` text is included. A partial solution that gets the first term is `stringr::str_extract(mydataframe[1,2], ".{0,8}GO.{0,8}")` but this only captures the first term.

Secondly the final output needs to be a named list of character vectors, with the list names being the first column and each element of the list being a character vector. This is direct from the vignette of the R package I'm trying to use (topGO).

> The object returned by readMappings is a named list of character
> vectors. The list names give the genes identifiers. Each element of
> the list is a character vector and contains the GO identifiers
> annotated to the specific gene

I know this is simple but I'm just getting stuck trying to use `apply` or some other solution and my brain is on strike.

Repex:

```
myvector1 <- c("Some_text_String")
myvector2 <- c("GO:0048046^cellular_component^apoplast`GO:0005618^cellular_component^cell wall`")
mydataframe <-  data.frame(myvector1,myvector2)

# parse myvector2 to remove everything except GO terms.
# This code only gets the first term, but I need all of them as a vector
stringr::str_extract(mydataframe [1,2], ".{0,8}GO.{0,8}")
# At this point the desired result is named list of character vectors, with the list names being the first column and each element of the list being a character vector.
```

Comment: Can you add your data using `dput` and show expected output for that. Read how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know how to produce a reproducible example. I can't show the data and expected output for confidentiality reasons. I thought I had provided enough detail, to be honest.

Comment: You don't have to share real data. You can prepare some fake data which is similar to your actual data using which we can verify our answers.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Minimal repex added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `str_extract_all` to extract all the values that satisfy the pattern and use `setNames` to get a named list.

```
library(stringr)
setNames(str_extract_all(mydataframe [1,2], "GO.{0,8}"), mydataframe$myvector1)

#$Some_text_String
#[1] "GO:0048046" "GO:0005618"
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks. There's a spelling error (library not librart), just fix and I'll accept the answer gratefully. Here's a slightly more generalised solution I'm using. `setNames(stringr::str_extract_all(mydataframe [1:nrow(mydataframe),20], "GO.{0,8}"), mydataframe$nyvector1 )`